# How can i use left join in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I don't want the query to select anything if the where clause is not fullfilled, but maybe i am missing something. Following is the query i am using

```
SELECT one.id_user, integration, data
FROM tableOne one
LEFT JOIN tableTwo two ON two.id_user = one.id_user
AND two.integration IN ('office', 'Office')
WHERE one.state='NEW' OR one.state='PAUSED'
AND two.integration IN ('office', 'Office')
GROUP BY one.id_user
```

The record is inserted in the required table with integration "SomeValue" and not "office" or "Office" which means the where claus should not be true and the query should not return anything, but it does. It returns id_user and rest of the fields as null.

But i don't it to select even the id_user if the integration is not "office" or "Office".

Can someone tell me please what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is your problem? and please clarify with example...

Comment: Don't put conditions on the right side table (tableTwo) in the where clause, move to ON clause to get true left join behavior. (As it is now it executes as a regular inner join.) Edit: already there, so just remove from where.

Comment: try replacing OR to AND in line: one.state='NEW' OR one.state='PAUSED'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see you made 2 errornous assumptions there.

The first is the sql statement is NOT a left join. As strange as it sounds. The reason behind this is that you use the 2nd table that is joined via left join in the where statement. This transforms the whole left join into an inner form instead.

The second assumption is that

```
one.state='NEW' OR one.state='PAUSED' AND two.integration IN ('office', 'Office')
```

does not display anything if two.integration is not (O)office. The and is stronger as the or which means in effect you have

```
(one.state='NEW') OR (one.state='PAUSED' AND two.integration IN ('office', 'Office'))
```

Thus if state is NEW then it does not matter what integration has as value. 
You should correct this to:

```
((one.state='NEW') OR one.state='PAUSED') AND two.integration IN ('office', 'Office')
```

to get the desired result there.

Then you still have the problem with inner join and left join though. In essence you would have to move the two.integration part into the left join on part if you really WANT a left join there (which your problem description does not sound like). If you want an inner join instead you should rename the join part and put all of the where parts into the on part of the inner join:

```
            SELECT one.id_user, integration, data
            FROM tableOne one
            INNER JOIN tableTwo two ON two.id_user = one.id_user
            AND two.integration IN ('office', 'Office')
            AND (one.state='NEW' OR one.state='PAUSED')
            GROUP BY one.id_user
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT one.id_user, integration, data
FROM tableOne ONE
INNER JOIN tableTwo two ON two.id_user = one.id_user
WHERE one.state IN ('NEW', 'PAUSED') AND two.integration IN ('office', 'Office')
GROUP BY one.id_user;
```

Comment: Funny, that the *only* answer *without* an explanation gets the upvote.

Answer (score 0):

First of all a `LEFT JOIN` is an outer join keeping records from the left table even when there are no matches in the right table. So why are you using it at all when you only want matches? Make this an `INNER JOIN` (or simply `JOIN` for that matter).

Then, when mixing AND and OR use parentheses:

```
one.state='NEW' OR one.state='PAUSED' AND two.integration IN ('office', 'Office')
```

means

```
one.state='NEW' OR (one.state='PAUSED' AND two.integration IN ('office', 'Office'))
```

where you want it to mean

```
(one.state='NEW' OR one.state='PAUSED') AND two.integration IN ('office', 'Office')
```

propably.

Answer (score 0):

Your `where` clause is turning the `left join` into an `inner join`.  Why?  Because the condition on `two` will fail when the values are `NULL`.

So, your intention is probably:

```
SELECT one.id_user, integration, data
FROM tableOne one LEFT JOIN 
     tableTwo two
     ON two.id_user = one.id_user AND
        two.integration IN ('office', 'Office')
WHERE one.state IN ('NEW', 'PAUSED')
GROUP BY one.id_user;
```

There is no need to repeat filtering conditions in both the `where` and `on` clauses -- in fact, it produces incorrect results for this query.

In addition, the `GROUP BY` might be causing other problems, because `integration` and `data` may be coming from arbitrary (matching) rows.  However, that is not the jist of your your question.